# Mac OSX CodeBlocks specify a debugger error

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, codeblocks

I am utilizing OSX and CodeBlocks to complete a C++ course.

I have no problem with compiling code.

I have command line tools and xcode both installed on my device.

I have also tried correcting the error as specified the message. However when I try to debug a program I get the following error:

```
ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings.
(For GCC compilers, it's 'gdb' (without the quotes))
```

Comment: You probably don't need to do any of this. You should be able to write and debug all the code you need in XCode. Code::Blocks is just another tool for writing and debugging C++, and since you already have XCode, why fight? Use XCode.

Comment: Yes that is true; however, it is my understanding he wants the entire CodeBlocks project dir when we turn in assignments. I could write in xcode but I would have to copy-paste everything into CodeBlocks. If I could remove that step it would be nice.

Comment: That's a real shame. All the marker needs is the cpp and h files. I'd check with them for confirmation. I hope this doesn't mean he instructor thinks Code::Blocks actually means something or is planning for you to use stuff like WinBGI. That would give you real problems on a Mac. Not to mention BGI has been obsolete for about 25 years.

Comment: If your instructor really insists on Code::Blocks, may be, the most pragmatic solution would be to do the development and debugging in XCode. Once, your solution is running, you could setup a project in Code::Blocks for submission. If I remember right OSX uses clang per-default. For your luck, clang as well as gcc are known for supporting the C++ standards quite good. If you don't use any exotic feature, it should be easy to write C++ code which compiles with both compilers without any additional effort.